# Web deployment task failed (This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, publish

Publishing ASP.NET MVC 4 application to IIS 8 on my machine giving the following error :

> This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.

I am under Windows 10 and using VS 2013 Ultimate.
I installed web deploy 3.5 from web platform installer 5, and I made sure that the services are working

[image]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Solution 1**

I was able to solve this problem in the following way

1. Go to IIS
2. Right click on the website that you are publishing to and select **Edit Permissions**
3. Click the **Security** tab.
4. Click on **Edit** button
5. A Message box will appear which tell that the Permission was not correctly ordered.
6. Click **Reorder** on that message box.

[image]

**Solution 2**

Open the Command prompt (CMD) and execute the following two statements

```
icacls.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot /verify /T /C /L /Q
icacls.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot /reset /T /C /L /Q
```

note : *Maybe* you will want to open the CMD with Administrator privilege *(Maybe I am not sure)*

Cheers

Comment: Okay, that worked, but why did it work?  What does the error mean?

Comment: In recent versions, the "reorder" option is available after clicking in the "advanced" button.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the following command to fix it

**command prompt**

```
icacls.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<VIRTUAL DIRECTORY> /verify /T /C /L /Q
// If any entries are reported as being not in canonical order then run:
icacls.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<VIRTUAL DIRECTORY> /reset /T /C /L /Q
```

[Source](https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/5465/Access-control-list-is-not-in-canonical-form-and-therefore-cannot-be-modified)

**powershell**

```
$path = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<VIRTUAL DIRECTORY>
$acl = Get-Acl $path
Set-Acl $path $acl
```

[Source](https://serverfault.com/a/287702)

Answer (score 1):

You can *prevent* this problem by modifying your Visual Studio package generation parameters: In the PropertyGroup section of your pubxml file, add

```
<IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>
```