# Access control list not in canonical form

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, devops

Whenever I try to merge code between branches in Azure Devops, I get that the access control list is not in canonical form, and cannot check in.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to reproduce the problem you are facing without any sample code. The first possible reason I can think is due to your account, it may don't have permissions to the folder you're trying to publish to. Try publishing to a different folder. Also check if their is any branch policies that's restricting you to perform your task.

If you are doing any web deployment task check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968313) regarding a similar problem asked in Stack Overflow. Alternatively, you can use the Microsoft utility, icacls.exe, to check and reset the permissions as show below.

1. For the entries that are reported as being not in canonical order run:

   `icacls.exe "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" /reset /T /C /L /Q`
2. Verify fix by running:

   `icacls.exe "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" /verify /T /C /L /Q`

For more information check this [document](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX207866). Also check this [discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-agent-cannot-install-as-service-on-wi/656574) on Microsoft Developer Community. If it still doesn't solve your problem raise a ticket to Microsoft Azure Support.